# Which method can I transfer the mathematically processed data from the server partition to any front end instantly?

Tags: node.js, oracle, express

Hello I'am getting data from oracledb and I'm doing some work on them. 
I am currently changing the received data by performing mathematical operations every second. I can write every second that process in terminal. I' am asking now. 
How can I keep the data constantly changing when a request is sent to my server. WebSocket or socket.io or or different way. which way is the best for me and how can i do this example? so I want to show a constantly changing table in the front.

Comment: Can you explain more and and give details about the data flow ?

Comment: First I call the procedure, then I keep the incoming object and update it by calling the procedure again in a second. but I am updating according to several conditions. For example, if the customer numbers of the data from two objects are the same, update

Comment: Please edit your issue and add all information.   Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?